# Adjust Webpage height to User's Viewport

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I added media queries to my css files in order to make my website responsive. However, I noticed that there is an issue with the content being cut off at the bottom of the screen on smaller devices (netbooks and smartphones). How do you tailor the height to adjust to the viewer's screen size?

Right Results (longer screens):

[image]

Wrong Results (shorter screens):

[image]

Note that on this page, the intro section and text cuts off as the screen gets shorter. I'm not sure if it has something to do with me using percentage instead of pixels. What's the best way to combat this?

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body, html {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.main {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 75%;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
  transition: .3s;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav-bar {
  background-color: #4a235a;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.9;
  transition: .3s;
  box-shadow: 2px 0px 4px black;
  position: fixed;
}

.bio-feature {
    width: 100%;
    height: 35%;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.intro {
  color: white;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: "Quicksand" ;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  margin-left: 6%;
  margin-right: 6%;
}

#first-line-intro {
  padding-top: 1%;
}
    
.heading {
 /*  margin-top: 20px; */
}
    
h1 {
    color: white;
    font-family: "Quicksand" ;
    padding: 0;
    /* margin-top: -12px; */
    margin-bottom: 16px; 
    font-size: 2em;
}

h2 {
    color: cornflowerblue;
    margin: 15%;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-family: Quicksand;
}

h3 {
  font-family: Pacifico;
  padding: 3%;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: lemonchiffon;
  font-weight: bold;
}

h6 {
  font-family: Ubuntu;
  color: navy;
  font-weight: 600;
}


p {
    padding: 0;
    /*margin-bottom: -200px;*/
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.highlighted-text {
    color: lime;
}

.highlighted-text2 {
    color: darkred;
}

a {
  color: white;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;  
}

.frontend{
   height: 100vh;
   background-color: white;
   border-right: solid 2px white;
   
}

.frontend-text, .backend-text {
  font-family: Quicksand;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 6% 8%;
}

.frontend-img {
  margin-bottom: 6%;
}

#additional-skills {
  position: relative;
  top: 6%;
}

.backend{
   height: 100vh;
   background-color: #E6E6E6;
   text-align: center;
}

svg {
    width: 15%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 1%;
}

.php  {
  width: 23%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.mysql {
  width: 23%;
  margin-bottom: 7%;
}

.python {
  width: 18%;
  margin-bottom: 8%;
}

.html-css {
     text-align: center;
}

.jquery-bootstrap {
    text-align: center;
}

.col-sm-12 {
   
}


.nav-panel {
  padding: 10% 30%;
  margin-top: 10%;
}

.nav-panel li {
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 20%;
  border-bottom: solid 1px gray;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.nav-panel li:hover {
  color: gray;
}

.space {
  position: relative;
  left: 20px;
}

.active {
  color: cyan;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.active:hover {
  color: cyan;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.selected {
  color: cyan;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.selected:hover {
  color: cyan;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.nav-link {
  font-family: Muli;
  position: relative;
  right: 15px;
}

/*
.nav-link:hover {
  color: gray;
  text-decoration: none;
} */


.menu-icon {
  width: 30px;
  margin: 1.2%;
  padding: 0.05% 0.02%;
}

.menu-icon:hover {
  background-color: rgba(86, 101, 115, 0.3);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.hide-nav {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.expand-main {
  width: 100%;
}

.shift-h1 {
    margin-top: -1%;
}

.mobile-dropdown {
    display: none;
}

.mobile-menu-icon {
    display: none;
}

.copyright {
    display: none;
    color: dimgray;
}




/* MOBILE */
/* MEDIA QUERIES */


@media (min-width: 1000px) and (max-width: 1150px) {
  .intro {
     font-size: 1.2em;    
  }
    
  .nav-link {
    font-size: 0.8em;
  }

  h1 {
    font-size: 1.9em;
    }
}



@media (min-width: 800px) and (max-width: 1000px) {
   .intro {
    font-size: 1.1em;    
} 
    
  .nav-link {
    font-size: 0.9em;
  }
    
    
  h1 {
    font-size: 1.8em;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
    
  .intro {
    font-size: 1em;
    margin-left: 3%;
    margin-right: 3%;
}  
  
    
  h1 {
    font-size: 1.8em;
    }
    
  h3 {
    font-size: 0.8em;
  }
    
  .nav-link {
    font-size: 0.9em;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 750px) {
    .nav-bar {
       
    }
    
    .main {
        
    }
    
    .nav-link {
    font-size: 0.8em;
  }
    
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
   .bio-feature {
    height: 40%;
} 
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    
  h1 {
    font-size: 1.9em;
  }

  .heading {
    position: relative; 
    top: 40px; 
  }
 
  .main {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .nav-bar {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .menu-icon {
    display: none;
  }
  
    .bio-feature {
   /* height: 30%; */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

    
  .backend {
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
    }
  
  body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: auto;
    }
  
  .mobile-background {
    background-color: #4a235a; 
   }
    
  .nav-bar {
    display: none;
    }
    
  .main {
     width: 100%;   
    }
    
  .menu-icon {
    display: none;
    }
   
  .mobile-menu-icon {
    margin: 3% 5%;
    width: 24px;
    padding: 0;
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
  
   .mobile-dropdown {
     width: 100%;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
    }
    
   .mobile-li {
     width: 100%;
     margin: 0px;
     color: white;
     background-color: #4a235a;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     list-style-type: none;
     padding: 2%;
     border-bottom: solid 2px gray;
     font-size: 1em;   
     float: left;
    }
    
   .mobile-a {
     font-family: Muli;
    } 
    
   .mobile-a:hover {
     text-decoration: none;
     color: gray;
    } 
    
    .active {
      color: cyan;
    }
    
    .active:hover {
      color: cyan;  
    }
    
    .button:hover {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .selected {
      color:  cyan;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    .selected:hover {
      color: cyan;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    .contact {
      border-bottom: none;
    }
    
   .expand {
     height: 100%;  
    }
    
  .mobile-menu-icon {
    display: block;
}
    
  .mobile-menu-icon:hover {
  background-color: rgba(86, 101, 115, 0.1);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
    
  .purple-background {
      background-color: #4a235a; 
}
    
}


@media (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 600px) {
  a {
  color: gainsboro;
  }
    
  .bio-feature {
    height: 42%;
}
}

@media (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 600px) {
  .heading {
    position: relative; 
    top: 60px; 
  }
    
  .intro {
    font-size: 1.1em;    
  }
}

@media (max-width: 550px) {
    .frontend, .backend {
        height: 100%;
    }
    
    .frontend-text, .backend-text {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    
    .copyright {
        display: block;
        font-size: 0.9em;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
}


@media (max-width: 500px) {
    .heading {
        position: relative;
        bottom: 30px;
    } 
}

@media (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 500px) {
        .intro {
        margin: 0 8%;
    }
}


@media (max-width: 400px) {
 h1 {
    font-size: 1.7em;
  }
    
 .bio-feature {
    height: 43%;
}
}

@media (max-width: 310px) {
    .intro {
        font-size: 0.95em;
    }
}




/* Add dropdown menu at 600px and down for this page */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Gab's Tech Space</title>

  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css'>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="gabsTechSpace_about.css">

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
      
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
      
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/konpa/devicon/df6431e323547add1b4cf45992913f15286456d3/devicon.min.css">
</head>

<body>

<a href=#><img class="mobile-menu-icon" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/30/Ic_menu_36px.svg/2000px-Ic_menu_36px.svg.png"></a>
    
<div class="mobile-dropdown collapse-nav"> 
  <ul>
      <li class="mobile-li"><a class="mobile-a" href="gabsTechSpace_home.html">Home</a></li>
      <li class="mobile-li"><a class="selected mobile-a" href="gabsTechSpace_about.html">About</a></li>
      <li class="mobile-li"><a class="mobile-a" href="gabsTechSpace_projects.html">Projects</a></li>
      <li class="mobile-li contact"><a class="mobile-a" href="gabsTechSpace_contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
    </div> 
    
<div class="main">
  <div class="bio-feature">
  <a href=#><img class="menu-icon" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/30/Ic_menu_36px.svg/2000px-Ic_menu_36px.svg.png"></a>
  <div class="heading">
  <h1 class="text-center">Gabrielle Rutherford</h1>
  <p class="intro text-center"><span id="first-line-intro">I'm a frontend developer working in the Houston Metro Area. </span><br> I often spend my free time delving deeper into the fascinating, yet incessant world of coding and design. And into pretty much anything else that stimulates my creative flair... I've realized that my destiny is to <strong>create things</strong> that will have an astounding impact on other people's lives.</p>
  </div>
  </div>
    
  <div class="skills">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 frontend">
          <h2 class="text-center">Frontend Skills</h2>
          
        <div class="frontend-img">
          <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12 html-css">
          <svg class="html5" viewBox="0 0 128 128">
<path fill="#E44D26" d="M19.037 113.876l-10.005-112.215h109.936l-10.016 112.198-45.019 12.48z"></path><path fill="#F16529" d="M64 116.8l36.378-10.086 8.559-95.878h-44.937z"></path><path fill="#EBEBEB" d="M64 52.455h-18.212l-1.258-14.094h19.47v-13.762h-34.511l.33 3.692 3.382 37.927h30.799zM64 88.198l-.061.017-15.327-4.14-.979-10.975h-13.817l1.928 21.609 28.193 7.826.063-.017z"></path><path fill="#fff" d="M63.952 52.455v13.763h16.947l-1.597 17.849-15.35 4.143v14.319l28.215-7.82.207-2.325 3.234-36.233.335-3.696h-3.708zM63.952 24.599v13.762h33.244l.276-3.092.628-6.978.329-3.692z"></path>
</svg> 
          
          <svg class="css3" viewBox="0 0 128 128">
<path fill="#1572B6" d="M18.814 114.123l-10.054-112.771h110.48l-10.064 112.754-45.243 12.543-45.119-12.526z"></path><path fill="#33A9DC" d="M64.001 117.062l36.559-10.136 8.601-96.354h-45.16v106.49z"></path><path fill="#fff" d="M64.001 51.429h18.302l1.264-14.163h-19.566v-13.831h34.681999999999995l-.332 3.711-3.4 38.114h-30.95v-13.831z"></path><path fill="#EBEBEB" d="M64.083 87.349l-.061.018-15.403-4.159-.985-11.031h-13.882l1.937 21.717 28.331 7.863.063-.018v-14.39z"></path><path fill="#fff" d="M81.127 64.675l-1.666 18.522-15.426 4.164v14.39l28.354-7.858.208-2.337 2.406-26.881h-13.876z"></path><path fill="#EBEBEB" d="M64.048 23.435v13.831000000000001h-33.407999999999994l-.277-3.108-.63-7.012-.331-3.711h34.646zM64.001 51.431v13.831000000000001h-15.209l-.277-3.108-.631-7.012-.33-3.711h16.447z"></path>
              </svg>
              
              </div>
             </div>
          
          <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12 jquery-bootstrap">
          <svg class="jquery" viewBox="0 0 128 128">
<path fill="#0868AC" d="M9.625 32.181c-11.029 15.851-9.656 36.476-1.231 53.32.2.404.41.801.617 1.198l.394.759.246.437.439.786c.262.461.53.92.804 1.379l.459.756c.304.491.615.976.933 1.46l.398.614c.439.655.888 1.309 1.352 1.951l.039.05.228.308c.401.553.814 1.099 1.232 1.639l.464.59c.373.469.752.935 1.138 1.399l.435.52c.518.61 1.047 1.217 1.586 1.812l.033.033.061.068c.527.575 1.066 1.137 1.612 1.699l.517.521c.423.426.853.845 1.287 1.262l.527.5c.58.547 1.166 1.083 1.764 1.607l.028.022.307.262c.527.456 1.063.909 1.603 1.353l.664.529c.441.354.887.702 1.336 1.044l.714.543c.496.365.995.724 1.499 1.075l.546.387.15.107c.478.329.967.646 1.456.963l.63.42c.75.474 1.51.943 2.279 1.396l.63.355c.565.326 1.134.646 1.71.959.312.168.632.327.946.488.407.213.811.429 1.225.636l.283.137.501.242c.641.306 1.287.607 1.94.897l.41.184c.748.327 1.502.641 2.263.941l.551.217c.704.271 1.418.539 2.135.791l.268.093c.787.275 1.581.53 2.381.779l.575.172c.814.245 1.619.538 2.458.693 53.339 9.727 68.833-32.053 68.833-32.053-13.013 16.953-36.111 21.425-57.996 16.446-.829-.187-1.633-.446-2.442-.685l-.609-.185c-.79-.242-1.573-.497-2.352-.765l-.323-.117c-.698-.245-1.387-.504-2.074-.769l-.582-.229c-.752-.297-1.5-.607-2.239-.931l-.447-.198c-.635-.288-1.263-.578-1.889-.879l-.546-.262c-.491-.239-.977-.493-1.461-.743-.324-.171-.654-.332-.975-.51-.592-.317-1.172-.646-1.751-.982l-.591-.33c-.769-.452-1.528-.921-2.28-1.397l-.615-.41c-.545-.351-1.088-.709-1.623-1.079l-.522-.367c-.516-.365-1.027-.734-1.534-1.109l-.679-.514c-.465-.355-.927-.713-1.384-1.082l-.617-.495c-.582-.479-1.156-.959-1.724-1.453l-.189-.159c-.614-.539-1.216-1.092-1.812-1.647l-.511-.491c-.441-.42-.875-.843-1.302-1.277l-.51-.509c-.543-.556-1.076-1.119-1.598-1.69l-.079-.084c-.552-.604-1.092-1.221-1.621-1.844l-.424-.504c-.394-.475-.785-.956-1.167-1.442l-.427-.532c-.459-.596-.908-1.189-1.347-1.794-12.15-16.574-16.516-39.432-6.805-58.204M43.862 18.825c-7.977 11.478-7.543 26.844-1.321 38.983 1.043 2.035 2.216 4.01 3.528 5.889 1.195 1.713 2.52 3.751 4.106 5.127.575.633 1.176 1.251 1.79 1.858l.472.465c.596.578 1.201 1.146 1.828 1.698l.074.064.018.018c.693.608 1.408 1.191 2.135 1.767l.485.378c.729.559 1.472 1.107 2.233 1.631l.065.049c.336.232.678.448 1.019.672l.483.319c.544.349 1.095.689 1.655 1.015l.235.136c.483.278.972.552 1.463.818l.521.271c.339.177.678.358 1.023.53l.155.07c.703.346 1.412.68 2.136.995l.472.194c.579.246 1.164.486 1.75.71l.75.275c.533.198 1.068.378 1.607.559l.727.233c.767.238 1.525.539 2.324.672 41.183 6.823 50.691-24.886 50.691-24.886-8.57 12.343-25.168 18.233-42.879 13.635-.787-.207-1.562-.431-2.333-.674l-.701-.227c-.548-.177-1.092-.365-1.631-.562l-.736-.274c-.592-.228-1.176-.462-1.756-.708l-.473-.2c-.727-.316-1.443-.65-2.148-.999-.363-.177-.72-.364-1.078-.548l-.622-.32c-.458-.248-.914-.506-1.363-.77l-.326-.185c-.558-.325-1.107-.661-1.651-1.008l-.498-.332c-.359-.232-.717-.469-1.069-.707-.759-.524-1.498-1.072-2.226-1.628l-.501-.395c-7.752-6.12-13.898-14.486-16.819-23.971-3.062-9.836-2.402-20.878 2.903-29.84M72.657 8.847c-4.702 6.92-5.164 15.514-1.901 23.156 3.441 8.113 10.491 14.476 18.72 17.495.339.125.679.237 1.022.354l.451.143c.485.152.966.329 1.467.424 22.74 4.394 28.908-11.669 30.549-14.034-5.402 7.779-14.482 9.646-25.623 6.942-.88-.213-1.847-.531-2.695-.832-1.088-.388-2.16-.83-3.201-1.329-1.978-.951-3.864-2.104-5.612-3.424-9.969-7.565-16.162-21.994-9.657-33.745"></path>
</svg>
          <svg class="bootstrap" viewBox="0 0 128 128">
<path fill="#5B4282" d="M75.701 65.603c-2.334-.768-5.694-.603-10.08-.603h-17.621v23h18.844c2.944 0 5.012-.315 6.203-.535 2.099-.376 3.854-1.104 5.264-1.982 1.409-.876 2.568-2.205 3.478-3.881.908-1.676 1.363-3.637 1.363-5.83 0-2.568-.658-4.54-1.975-6.436-1.316-1.896-3.141-2.965-5.476-3.733zM73.282 55.087c2.317-.688 4.064-1.89 5.239-3.487 1.176-1.598 1.763-3.631 1.763-6.044 0-2.286-.549-4.314-1.646-6.054s-2.662-2.413-4.699-3.056c-2.037-.641-5.53-.446-10.48-.446h-15.459v20h16.587c4.042 0 6.939-.38 8.695-.913zM126 18.625c0-9.182-7.443-16.625-16.625-16.625h-91.75c-9.182 0-16.625 7.443-16.625 16.625v91.75c0 9.182 7.443 16.625 16.625 16.625h91.75c9.182 0 16.625-7.443 16.625-16.625v-91.75zm-35.447 66.12c-1.362 2.773-3.047 4.911-5.052 6.415-2.006 1.504-4.521 2.78-7.544 3.548-3.022.769-6.728 1.292-11.113 1.292h-27.844v-69h27.42c5.264 0 9.485.609 12.665 2.002 3.181 1.395 5.671 3.497 7.474 6.395 1.801 2.898 2.702 5.907 2.702 9.071 0 2.945-.8 5.708-2.397 8.308-1.598 2.602-4.011 4.694-7.237 6.292 4.166 1.222 7.37 3.304 9.61 6.248 2.24 2.945 3.36 6.422 3.36 10.432 0 3.227-.681 6.225-2.044 8.997z"></path>
</svg> 
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
          <h6 class="text-center">HTML5 - CSS3 - JQuery - Bootstrap 4</h6>
          <p class="frontend-text">From the design process to initiaton and launch, I love utilizing the newest frontend technologies to construct beautiful, functional, and responsive interfaces. <span class="highlighted-text">HTML5</span>, <span class="highlighted-text">CSS3</span>, <span class="highlighted-text">Bootstrap 4</span> and <span class="highlighted-text">JQuery</span> are all used in most of my frontend projects. In fact, they were all incorporated to build this site. </p>
          <br>
          <br>
    </div>
        
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 backend">
          <h2 class="text-center">Backend Skills</h2>
          <svg class="mysql" viewBox="0 0 128 128">
<path fill="#00618A" d="M2.001 90.458h4.108v-16.223l6.36 14.143c.75 1.712 1.777 2.317 3.792 2.317s3.003-.605 3.753-2.317l6.36-14.143v16.223h4.108v-16.196c0-1.58-.632-2.345-1.936-2.739-3.121-.974-5.215-.131-6.163 1.976l-6.241 13.958-6.043-13.959c-.909-2.106-3.042-2.949-6.163-1.976-1.304.395-1.936 1.159-1.936 2.739v16.197zM33.899 77.252h4.107v8.938c-.038.485.156 1.625 2.406 1.661 1.148.018 8.862 0 8.934 0v-10.643h4.117c.019 0-.004 14.514-.004 14.574.022 3.58-4.441 4.357-6.499 4.417h-12.972v-2.764c.022 0 12.963.003 12.995-.001 2.645-.279 2.332-1.593 2.331-2.035v-1.078h-8.731c-4.062-.037-6.65-1.81-6.683-3.85-.002-.187.089-9.129-.001-9.219z"></path><path fill="#E48E00" d="M56.63 90.458h11.812c1.383 0 2.727-.289 3.793-.789 1.777-.816 2.646-1.922 2.646-3.372v-3.002c0-1.185-.987-2.292-2.923-3.028-1.027-.396-2.292-.605-3.517-.605h-4.978c-1.659 0-2.449-.5-2.646-1.606-.039-.132-.039-.237-.039-.369v-1.87c0-.105 0-.211.039-.342.197-.843.632-1.08 2.094-1.212l.395-.026h11.733v-2.738h-11.535c-1.659 0-2.528.105-3.318.342-2.449.764-3.517 1.975-3.517 4.082v2.396c0 1.844 2.095 3.424 5.61 3.793.396.025.79.053 1.185.053h4.267c.158 0 .316 0 .435.025 1.304.105 1.856.343 2.252.816.237.237.315.475.315.737v2.397c0 .289-.197.658-.592.974-.355.316-.948.527-1.738.58l-.435.026h-11.338v2.738zM100.511 85.692c0 2.817 2.094 4.397 6.32 4.714.395.026.79.052 1.185.052h10.706v-2.738h-10.784c-2.41 0-3.318-.606-3.318-2.055v-14.168h-4.108v14.195zM77.503 85.834v-9.765c0-2.48 1.742-3.985 5.186-4.46.356-.053.753-.079 1.108-.079h7.799c.396 0 .752.026 1.147.079 3.444.475 5.187 1.979 5.187 4.46v9.765c0 2.014-.74 3.09-2.445 3.792l4.048 3.653h-4.771l-3.274-2.956-3.296.209h-4.395c-.752 0-1.543-.105-2.414-.343-2.613-.712-3.88-2.085-3.88-4.355zm4.434-.237c0 .132.039.265.079.423.237 1.135 1.307 1.768 2.929 1.768h3.732l-3.428-3.095h4.771l2.989 2.7c.552-.295.914-.743 1.041-1.32.039-.132.039-.264.039-.396v-9.368c0-.105 0-.238-.039-.37-.238-1.056-1.307-1.662-2.89-1.662h-6.216c-1.82 0-3.008.792-3.008 2.032v9.288z"></path><path fill="#00618A" d="M122.336 66.952c-2.525-.069-4.454.166-6.104.861-.469.198-1.216.203-1.292.79.257.271.297.674.502 1.006.394.637 1.059 1.491 1.652 1.938.647.489 1.315 1.013 2.011 1.437 1.235.754 2.615 1.184 3.806 1.938.701.446 1.397 1.006 2.082 1.509.339.247.565.634 1.006.789v-.071c-.231-.294-.291-.698-.503-1.006l-.934-.934c-.913-1.212-2.071-2.275-3.304-3.159-.982-.705-3.18-1.658-3.59-2.801l-.072-.071c.696-.079 1.512-.331 2.154-.503 1.08-.29 2.045-.215 3.16-.503l1.508-.432v-.286c-.563-.578-.966-1.344-1.58-1.867-1.607-1.369-3.363-2.737-5.17-3.879-1.002-.632-2.241-1.043-3.304-1.579-.356-.181-.984-.274-1.221-.575-.559-.711-.862-1.612-1.293-2.441-.9-1.735-1.786-3.631-2.585-5.458-.544-1.245-.9-2.473-1.579-3.59-3.261-5.361-6.771-8.597-12.208-11.777-1.157-.677-2.55-.943-4.021-1.292l-2.37-.144c-.481-.201-.983-.791-1.436-1.077-1.802-1.138-6.422-3.613-7.756-.358-.842 2.054 1.26 4.058 2.011 5.099.527.73 1.203 1.548 1.58 2.369.248.54.29 1.081.503 1.652.521 1.406.976 2.937 1.651 4.236.341.658.718 1.351 1.149 1.939.264.36.718.52.789 1.077-.443.62-.469 1.584-.718 2.369-1.122 3.539-.699 7.938.934 10.557.501.805 1.681 2.529 3.303 1.867 1.419-.578 1.103-2.369 1.509-3.95.092-.357.035-.621.215-.861v.072l1.293 2.585c.957 1.541 2.654 3.15 4.093 4.237.746.563 1.334 1.538 2.298 1.867v-.073h-.071c-.188-.291-.479-.411-.719-.646-.562-.551-1.187-1.235-1.651-1.867-1.309-1.776-2.465-3.721-3.519-5.745-.503-.966-.94-2.032-1.364-3.016-.164-.379-.162-.953-.502-1.148-.466.72-1.149 1.303-1.509 2.154-.574 1.36-.648 3.019-.861 4.739l-.144.071c-1.001-.241-1.352-1.271-1.724-2.154-.94-2.233-1.115-5.83-.287-8.401.214-.666 1.181-2.761.789-3.376-.187-.613-.804-.967-1.148-1.437-.427-.579-.854-1.341-1.149-2.011-.77-1.741-1.129-3.696-1.938-5.457-.388-.842-1.042-1.693-1.58-2.441-.595-.83-1.262-1.44-1.724-2.442-.164-.356-.387-.927-.144-1.293.077-.247.188-.35.432-.431.416-.321 1.576.107 2.01.287 1.152.479 2.113.934 3.089 1.58.468.311.941.911 1.508 1.077h.646c1.011.232 2.144.071 3.088.358 1.67.508 3.166 1.297 4.524 2.155 4.139 2.614 7.522 6.334 9.838 10.772.372.715.534 1.396.861 2.154.662 1.528 1.496 3.101 2.154 4.596.657 1.491 1.298 2.996 2.227 4.237.488.652 2.374 1.002 3.231 1.364.601.254 1.585.519 2.154.861 1.087.656 2.141 1.437 3.16 2.155.509.362 2.076 1.149 2.154 1.798zM90.237 39.593c-.526-.01-.899.058-1.293.144v.071h.072c.251.517.694.849 1.005 1.293l.719 1.508.071-.071c.445-.313.648-.814.646-1.58-.179-.188-.205-.423-.359-.646-.204-.3-.602-.468-.861-.719z"></path>
</svg> 
          <svg class="php" viewBox="0 0 128 128">
<path fill="#6181B6" d="M64 33.039c-33.74 0-61.094 13.862-61.094 30.961s27.354 30.961 61.094 30.961 61.094-13.862 61.094-30.961-27.354-30.961-61.094-30.961zm-15.897 36.993c-1.458 1.364-3.077 1.927-4.86 2.507-1.783.581-4.052.461-6.811.461h-6.253l-1.733 10h-7.301l6.515-34h14.04c4.224 0 7.305 1.215 9.242 3.432 1.937 2.217 2.519 5.364 1.747 9.337-.319 1.637-.856 3.159-1.614 4.515-.759 1.357-1.75 2.624-2.972 3.748zm21.311 2.968l2.881-14.42c.328-1.688.208-2.942-.361-3.555-.57-.614-1.782-1.025-3.635-1.025h-5.79l-3.731 19h-7.244l6.515-33h7.244l-1.732 9h6.453c4.061 0 6.861.815 8.402 2.231s2.003 3.356 1.387 6.528l-3.031 15.241h-7.358zm40.259-11.178c-.318 1.637-.856 3.133-1.613 4.488-.758 1.357-1.748 2.598-2.971 3.722-1.458 1.364-3.078 1.927-4.86 2.507-1.782.581-4.053.461-6.812.461h-6.253l-1.732 10h-7.301l6.514-34h14.041c4.224 0 7.305 1.215 9.241 3.432 1.935 2.217 2.518 5.418 1.746 9.39zM95.919 54h-5.001l-2.727 14h4.442c2.942 0 5.136-.29 6.576-1.4 1.442-1.108 2.413-2.828 2.918-5.421.484-2.491.264-4.434-.66-5.458-.925-1.024-2.774-1.721-5.548-1.721zM38.934 54h-5.002l-2.727 14h4.441c2.943 0 5.136-.29 6.577-1.4 1.441-1.108 2.413-2.828 2.917-5.421.484-2.491.264-4.434-.66-5.458s-2.772-1.721-5.546-1.721z"></path>
</svg>
          <svg class="python" viewBox="0 0 128 128">
<path fill="#FFD845" d="M49.33 62h29.159c8.117 0 14.511-6.868 14.511-15.019v-27.798c0-7.912-6.632-13.856-14.555-15.176-5.014-.835-10.195-1.215-15.187-1.191-4.99.023-9.612.448-13.805 1.191-12.355 2.181-14.453 6.751-14.453 15.176v10.817h29v4h-40.224000000000004c-8.484 0-15.914 5.108-18.237 14.811-2.681 11.12-2.8 17.919 0 29.53 2.075 8.642 7.03 14.659 15.515 14.659h9.946v-13.048c0-9.637 8.428-17.952 18.33-17.952zm-1.838-39.11c-3.026 0-5.478-2.479-5.478-5.545 0-3.079 2.451-5.581 5.478-5.581 3.015 0 5.479 2.502 5.479 5.581-.001 3.066-2.465 5.545-5.479 5.545zM122.281 48.811c-2.098-8.448-6.103-14.811-14.599-14.811h-10.682v12.981c0 10.05-8.794 18.019-18.511 18.019h-29.159c-7.988 0-14.33 7.326-14.33 15.326v27.8c0 7.91 6.745 12.564 14.462 14.834 9.242 2.717 17.994 3.208 29.051 0 7.349-2.129 14.487-6.411 14.487-14.834v-11.126h-29v-4h43.682c8.484 0 11.647-5.776 14.599-14.66 3.047-9.145 2.916-17.799 0-29.529zm-41.955 55.606c3.027 0 5.479 2.479 5.479 5.547 0 3.076-2.451 5.579-5.479 5.579-3.015 0-5.478-2.502-5.478-5.579 0-3.068 2.463-5.547 5.478-5.547z"></path>
</svg> 
          <h6 class="text-center">SQL - PHP - Python</h6>
          <p class="backend-text">For both web development and application development projects in the future, I've been trying my hand at the <span class="highlighted-text2">Python</span> programming language. I'm also picking up <span class="highlighted-text2">SQL</span> to become comfortable with database management. <span class="highlighted-text2">PHP</span> was utilized for the contact form on this site.</p>
          <!--
          <h2 class="text-center" id="additional-skills">Additional Skills</h2>
          -->
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <p class="copyright">&copy; 2017 Gabby Rutherford</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="nav-bar">
    <a href="gabsTechSpace_home.html" class="logo"><h3>Gab's Tech <br><span class="space">Space</span></h3></a>
  <ul class="nav-panel text-center">
    <li><a href="gabsTechSpace_home.html" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="gabsTechSpace_about.html" class="nav-link active">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="gabsTechSpace_projects.html" class="nav-link">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="gabsTechSpace_contact.html" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>

  <script  src="gabsTechSpace_about.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use viewport units, `vh`, which are percentage of device height. If you want the upper part to never be cut off set it's heght to `auto` but you can't have both fit the screen if there is too much content.

Put a media query to set smaller font size on short screens if you think you can fit your content that way, like this

```
@media (max-height: 600px) {
    .box {
        font-size: 0.75rem;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, so should only the divs be measured in vh units or should everything be (the body included). I thought the media queries that I added already took care of the font-sizes.

Comment: You don't have any media queries that check for height. You are checking only for width in your code. Try it and you will fix the units later ;)

Comment: Thank you so much! Just setting the height of the element using vh and a single media query gave me the results I was looking for.